# Bad search filter

Tags: python, python-ldap

Im trying to filter few attributes from the ldap server but get errors,

```
ldap.FILTER_ERROR: {'desc': 'Bad search filter'}
```

Code:-

```
import ldap
ldap.OPT_REFERRALS = 0

ldap_server="ldapps.test.com"
username = "testuser"
password= "" #your password
connect = ldap.open(ldap_server)

dn='uid='+username;
print 'dn =', dn
try:
    result = connect.simple_bind_s(username,password)
    print 'connected == ', result
    filter1 = "(|(uid=" + username + "\*))"
    result = connect.search("DC=cable,DC=com,DC=com",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,filter1)
    print result

except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS as e:
    connect.unbind_s()
    print "authentication error == ", e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search filter is, in fact, bad.

The `|` character is for joining several conditions together in an `OR` statement.  For example, if you wanted to find people with a last name of "smith", "jones", or "baker", you would use this filter:

```
(|(lastname=smith)(lastname=jones)(lastname=baker))
```

However, your filter only has one condition, so there's nothing for the `|` character to join together.  Change your filter to this and it should work:

```
"(uid=" + username + "\*)"
```

By the way, what are you trying to do with the backslash and asterisk?  Are you looking for people whose usernames actually end with an asterisk?

Comment: Thanks that got fixed but I get response "2"(protocol error) always..Looks like a protocol error, I tried adding ldap.LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION = ldap.VERSION3 but still get the same error, ...Here is my new search string for now, filter1 = "(uid=test)"
 result1 = connect.search("DC=cable",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,filter1)

Comment: Try using `"DC=cable,DC=com,DC=com"` as your search base instead of just `"DC=cable"`.

Comment: Tried that still have the same issue

Comment: It's odd that you didn't get this error originally.  What else did you change?

Comment: Actually, this is the first time I get this error while searching for the attributes. My simple_bind_s works without any issues